# Create link that only works outside of div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div>
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
Some background html for the entire page
```

With the following CSS:

```
div.popup
{
    z-index:999;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}

div.popup div
{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

My goal is to make it possible to click anywhere in the outer div to navigate to a different page. I tried it by encapsulating the outer div with a `<a href="?" title="cancel">` tag, and tried an `OnClick="alert(test);"` on the outer div, part, but both of them will also trigger when the inner div is clicked.

I also tried to give the inner div a z-index of 9999 to make it pop out, but that didn't work either.

How can I make it so that I can click anywhere in the outer div to go to a page, whereas it won't happen if I click on the inner div?

Comment: Can you use JQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: If you can get me something that solves the problem, probably yes, though I am not very experienced with JQuery or Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the bubbling. The event will go from the child up to the container (and to the `body`, `html`, etc), and your container handler will be notified. To prevent that, tell the browser to stop the bubbling right at that point, using `event.stopPropagation()`:

```css
div.popup
{
    z-index:999;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}

div.popup div
{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="alert('will go to another page')">
    <div onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
Some background html for the entire page
```

Comment: Awesome, that does it. I already tested 2 alerts to see if the inner would block the outer, but both were fired, so I already seen that this happened. Didn't know you can actually stop that with stopPropagation. This solved it for me. +1 too. :)